# Codeigniter showing problem with date function

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to insert values into db. I have a table as registration_patients. My code is:

```
$data = array(
    'patients_first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
    'patients_last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
    'patients_email' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'patients_password'=> $this->input->post('password'),
    'patients_birth_date'=> date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('day') . "-" .$this->input->post('month') . "-" . $this->input->post('year'))),
    'patients_sex'=> $this->input->post('sex'),
    'patients_telephone'=> $this->input->post('telephone'),
    'patients_codice_fiscale'=> $this->input->post('codice_fiscale'),
    'account_active'=> 0
    );
    return $this->db->insert('registration_patients', $data);
```

Now it is inserted values into database bus showing some error and warning like that

> A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

> Message: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for
>   'BST/1.0/DST' instead

Filename: models/doctors_model.php

> Line Number: 22 and A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for
>   'BST/1.0/DST' instead
>
> Filename: models/doctors_model.php
>
> Line Number: 22

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `root_folder/index.php` write `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');` and see if the problem is solved or not. Here is the [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) of `available timezones`.

Comment: Thank you man.i put date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
in config.php.Now it is not showing error.

Comment: This can also be set in your php.ini file as `date.timezone = America/New_York`.  You will no longer have to concern yourself with adding it to each application, or changing your application to fit whatever server timezone you are on.

Comment: Yes, true, but what if you need to set each of your application to different time zones? It depends upon your need. Setting it application wise gives you more flexibility. @jbo5112